# Prevent Loop jQuery

Tags: jquery, slide, slideup

I created this script for scrolling up with jQuery, but when you mouseover and mouseout multiple times, the script goes into the loop until it finishes for every time you mouse over it.

I already tried to search for a solution but I didn't sorted it out, here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.desc').hide();  

    $('.work').mouseover(function(){
        $('.desc', this).slideDown('900');  
    });

    $('.work').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.desc', this).slideUp('900');    
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), notice passing true as both the args, its clears the queue(read the docs for more information) and jumps to the end. if you dont pass true as the args the animations will be queued and executed so you will face the same behavior as you are facing at the moment

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.desc').hide();  

    $('.work').mouseover(function(){
        $('.desc', this).stop(true,true).slideDown('900');  
    });

    $('.work').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.desc', this).slideUp('900');    
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before each animation (slideUp and slideDown). This little function stops the animation before adding a new one to the animation queue!

Answer (score 0):

Add `stop()` before each animation, which clears the animation queue. http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.desc').hide();  

    $('.work').mouseover(function(){
        $('.desc', this).stop().slideDown('900');  
    });

    $('.work').mouseleave(function(){
        $('.desc', this).stop().slideUp('900');    
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.stop()` will help on paper, but animation will still look jerky. What you really looking for is delayed hover event to trigger animation when user actually "hovering" over your `.work` element. There are a few jQuery plugins for that. Try out [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) - [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/Pevpp/). Or you could write your own, which isn't terribly hard either.

Also FYI 900 is almost a full second - that is way longer than a polite animation should be.